# Why is the code below 'return next()' still being executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, middleware

As I understood `next()`, it stops the middleware function and moves on (to the next middleware). Here, however the second then()-method is executed ignoring the next().
This leads to an error in my code, if the user already exists and nothing is inserted. Using just next() without return, didn't help.

```
function middlewareFunction(req, res, next) {
   const id = req.body.id;
   database.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", id)
        .then(result => {          
            
            if(result.length) { // user is already stored in db
                console.log("User already exists");
                req.body.userId = result[0].id;
                return next();
            } else { // user isnt stored in db, storing user first time
                console.log("User doens't exist yet, storing user.")
                return database.query("INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (?)", id)
            }
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log("Insert result:", result);
            req.body.userId = result.insertId;
            console.log("User got id:", result.insertId);
            return next();
        })
}
```

The middleware should end when either the user exists(first next()) or the new user is inserted(second next()).

Comment: `next()` signals to whatever called `middlewareFunction` that your middleware is done. It doesn't change how Javascript code as such works. If you returned anything else, `return foo()`, how would you expect the promise chain to behave…?

Comment: The second then() would be executed.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: bad coding, use async/await and promisify to control promise function more easily

Comment: Something like `const result = await database.query('SELECT * FROM user')`? @deko_39

Comment: @Nothere, that's it. make life easier